# Time Travel Debugging in Python - what tools are suggested to use?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I was recently wondering about *Time Travel Debugging* in relation to Python. 
I found information about tools like:

- *RevPDB* - unfortunately the last recorded activity is from 2016
- *timetravelpdb* - unfortunately the last recorded activity is in 2015

Since the projects were updated so long ago, I was wondering if the tools used for TTD had changed for the moment?

I am counting on constructive discussion and advice & suggestions what to use now.
It is all about sharing the knowledge.

Comment: This kind of question seems to be off-topic for this forum. Maybe you'd have better chances to get an answer to such a question in other communities. Maybe this one: https://discuss.python.org/c/users/7

Comment: Ok @sinoroc, thanks for your advice. 

Actually, is the purpose of knowledge sharing not within this community?

Comment: It is. I am not saying you won't get an answer here, I'm saying you might be more likely to get an answer from other communities, such as the one I linked. And wherever you happen to find an answer you are more than welcome to share these findings here, by answering your own question. -- Also, maybe this: https://pytrace.com/

Comment: When I finish doing the research, I will gladly present the results to the whole community.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### General Overview of TTD Research

---

At this very moment, available solutions are those listed in the description of the question and additionally ***PyTrace***.

As far as ***RevPDB*** and ***timetravelpdb*** are concerned, I haven't tested these solutions in any way as the activity in these projects is registered a few years ago so I assumed that in case of problems contact with the support will be difficult.

### How to start working with it?

To start with, it is worth using an interactive demo to learn about the basic functionalities and the way it works:

[PyTrace Interactive Demo](https://app.pytrace.com/?open=v0.1-interactive-demo)

If you need more information, check this site:

[PyTrace Official Site](https://pytrace.com/)

I am impressed with this project and I'm going to start using it in my daily coding routine so I will post my thought and tips about it later.

*Stay tuned!*

Comment: You are missing https://pythontutor.com/ time-traveling debugger focused on beginners and learners

Comment: pythontutor.com has a very appealing user interface. But they require uploading my code to their server and running it there. (A) My code might be proprietary (as mine certainly is), and (B) their server won't be reproducing the conditions and resources in my production environment. Looks like PyTrace for me.